# Checking if any letters in my ddict has a value greater than one, if so print some text, if not convert to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to recreate the enigma code in python, currently I am working on getting the switchboard settings and to do this I want to make sure no letters are repeated in the input (which format is "AB CD EF GH" etc.) currently I am checking how many of each letter is in the inputted string by using a default dict. I want to be able to print an error if there is any repetition, or if not store the values in a list. (Like [AB,CD,EF,GH]) After a lot of looking I have not found anything so hope you can help. The code is below.

```
global SwitchboardSettings
            global d
            NSwitchboardSettings = input("Enter the switchboard settings leaving a space between each, there should be 13 pairs: ")

            d = collections.defaultdict(int)
            for c in NSwitchboardSettings:  #Collections module, FIX
                d[c] += 1
```

Comment: Check [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count) and [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) out

Comment: Will a letter mean a pair of alphabets or just one alphabet?

Comment: A pair for the switchboard settings, yes

Comment: WoozyCoder Ah so I can just use .list() on the original var if there are no repeats, but still don't know how to check for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is a little broad and not very precise so I hope I'm right in this code example.

```
from string import ascii_letters

input_ok = 'AB CD EF gh ij'
input_nok = 'AB CD EF gh ij Ag'

# Searches for repeated characters
for ch in ascii_letters:
    count = input_nok.count(ch)
    if count > 1:
        print('{} is repeated {} times'.format(ch, count))
        # Do something else

# Convert pair of letters into a list
lst_ok = input_ok.split(' ')
lst_nok = input_nok.split(' ')

print(lst_ok)
print(lst_nok)
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!